# Moments and center of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass

"Moment" in physics is given by $\text{force} \times \text{distance}$.

However, when I was studying a topic *Moments and centers of mass*, in the chapter *Applications of integral*, it says that it is $\text{mass} \times \text{distance}$?

I.e. center of mass is
\begin{equation}
(\bar{x}) = \frac{\sum_k x_k M_k}{\sum_k M_k}
\end{equation}
where $\sum_k x_k M_k$ is the "moment of system about the origin" and $M_k$ is mass of system.

Comment: I cannot really locate the question. There is a question mark at the end of one sentence, but the sentence sounds like a statement. Are you asking whether there is such convention in the book? Or whether there is different convention between  math and physics? Or whether the book is wrong? Or something else?

Comment: Hey sry abt the question mark I just want to know why Xk Mk  i.e mass × distance was termed as moment in that chapter. if moment is defined as force × distance.

Answer (score 1):

A [moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(physics)) in physics is the product of a quantity at a point and the distance between that point and a fixed axis. So the moment in your first example is a moment of force (also called a torque) whereas the moment in your second example is a moment of mass.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a distribution, $\rho(x)$, defined relative to some measure, $x$, then the moments of the distribution about $c$ are:

$$\mu_n \equiv \int (x-c)^n\rho(x) dx $$

If $c=0$, they're call raw moments. While if $c=\mu_1$:

$$\mu_1 = \int x\rho(x)dx= \bar x   $$

they are centralized moments. If they are normalized w.r.t to the second central moment:

$$ \sigma^2=\int(x-\bar x)^2\rho(x)$$

ala:

$$ \frac{\mu_k}{\sigma^k}$$

then they are called standardized moments.

With that, torque, center-of-mass, moment-of-inertia tensor are all some sort of moment.